# How to combine a styles object with an inline style in React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to combine an inline style `transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}]` with an already existing styles object `styles.buttonText` without modifying the styles object.  I have tried the following ways:

```
<Text style={{...styles.buttonText, transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}]}}>^</Text>
```

and

```
<Text style={{...styles.buttonText, ...{transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}]}}}>^</Text>
```

and

```
<Text style={Object.assign({}, styles.buttonText, {transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}]})}>^</Text>
```

But I keep getting this same error message:

> TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an
>   object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec
>   compliant.

Does anyone know what is going on or how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to combine styles on a element you have to pass an array to the style property. The last item in the array will take precedence.

e.g:

```
<Text style={[styles.buttonText, {transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }]}]}>^</Text>
```

see style [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html)